# Jquery UI. Droppable after element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an issue regarding jquery Ui droppable.
I need to drop an element before or after the element it's dragged over. Is there anyway to detect which element it's over, and then append/prepend it in the parent container.

Right now, I just drops in the end of the div, because of append, I'm a little clueless.

I made a fiddle to hopefully better illustrate my issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/tsxzf80u/

```
$('section').droppable({
  accept:'.dragme',
  drop:function(event, ui){
     var div = $("<div />").addClass('full').html('test');
     $(this).append(div);
  }
 });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you make each of the divs inside of the section individually droppable, then use `after()`, seems to do what you want.

```
$('#fullId1, #fullId2').droppable({
    accept: '.dragme',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var div = $("<div />").addClass('full').html('test');
        $(this).after(div);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tsxzf80u/2/

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what i meant. This drops the div inside the other divs. It needs to drop between them. The divs in the parent div, and the draggable one, essentially is the same, nomatter how many gets added.